# Eliminate duplicate entries from my query results when using window function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given following query:

```
select *
from (
    select name, vote_date
        , sum(votes) over (partition by name) as total_votes
    from table
) as subq
where vote_date > '2023-01-01'
and total_votes > 4
```

This is a sample output:

| vote_date | name | total_votes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-08 | Alex | 6 |
| 2023-07-14 | Bob | 8 |
| 2023-07-19 | Bob | 8 |
| 2023-04-18 | Carol | 9 |
| 2023-02-03 | Carol | 9 |
| 2023-07-20 | Diana | 10 |
| 2023-05-22 | Diana | 10 |
| 2023-08-21 | Rizlf | 10 |
| 2023-09-27 | Rizlf | 10 |

I want to eliminate duplicates form my results and only show one entry for each name with the total_votes. The data has the same person voting across multiple days

I have tried to use a GROUP BY name but I get an error. Column 'subq.vote_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I have also tried removing the vote_date from the subquery but I get another error I think because I need it for the WHERE clause.

Comment: The query you posted should not be generating this error.  And also, what is the exact output you expect here?

Comment: So for Bob, which date do you want? Why?

Comment: I think the output matches the expected result, but now I'm trying to eliminate duplicates from the results and I'm not sure how to proceed given that a GROUP BY generated an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why vote_date is in the output. Maybe you just want:

```
SELECT name, SUM(votes) as total_votes
FROM dbo.tableName
WHERE vote_date > '20230101'
GROUP BY name;
```

Or if you want the *last* date per person:

```
SELECT name, 
  MAX(vote_date) as last_vote,
  SUM(votes) as total_votes
FROM dbo.tableName
WHERE vote_date > '20230101'
GROUP BY name;
```

But having all the vote dates in the output and also trying to group by it or eliminate duplicates that are only different in the column can’t all be done at the same time.

Comment: Yeah I don't need the date in the final output and doing a select distinct name fixes the issue

Comment: @drum I don’t think you should use distinct, but I also don’t think you should be using OVER(). DISTINCT often causes more work because it can filter rows too late. You use OVER() basically when you want an aggregate but you _don’t_ want to remove duplicates.

Comment: what do you suggest I use instead of OVER? I need to use partition by

Comment: @drum I don’t know, does this answer get the result you want? If so, why do you think you need partition by?

Comment: Partially I just didn't need to display the date. I don't have to use select distinct either I can just pick the name and total_votes

Comment: Okay, well, I don’t know how to help. Your requirements are jumping all over the place and it’s too late at night here to follow along.